# I need to calculate the average power spectral density after passing packets through a butterworth filter using MATLAB

Tags: filter, matlab, digital-communications, noise-spectral-density

[image: image for 8192 point fft]
I am trying to generate 100 packets(row vectors each of size 8192) of random bits(1,-1),filter them using butterworth filter and then plot their average power spectral density. I have to do this using MATLAB.My o/p should be a filtered sinc with a very sharp peak with small sidelobes. I can't get the desired output. I want someone to review my code for modifications please.
I have attached the image of my output as well(which is wrong).

```
%generates a random square matrix of 8192x8192
n=rand(8192);
%initiates a row vector of 64 zeros
B=zeros(1,64);
%makes a butterworth(lowpass) filter
[num,den]=butter(20,.6); 
%two for loops to generate 100 row vectors(packets) each of size 8192 that
%give 1 for any value greater than 0.5 and vice versa
for c=1:100
for k=1:8192
if n(c,k)>=0.5
n(c,k)=1;
else
n(c,k)=-1;
end
%filter the generated vectors and calculate average power spectral density
x=filter(num,den,n(c,:));
A=fftshift(fft(x,64));
psd=A.*conj(A);
B=B+psd;
end
end
plot(B./100)
xlabel 'Frequency', ylabel 'Average Power Spectral Density'
```

Comment: What have you tried? You should phrase your question and explain where, specifically, you are having problems. Post any error messages, if applicable. Don't just paste code as the body of your question and expect that to get an answer. Finally, when you do include code, format it using the `{}` button.

Comment: Sorry I am just a beginner here.
I am trying to generate 100 packets(row vectors each of size 8192) of random bits(1,-1),filter them using butterworth filter and then plot their average power spectral density.
I have to do this using MATLAB.My o/p should be a filtered sinc. When I use this code for smaller sized packets say 500 it works. But for 8192 it doesn't. I want someone to review my code for errors please.

Comment: @Samia, you can edit your question at any time to add that information, it's better than including additional information in comments. While editing you can also use the code formatting button JYelton mentioned and check that it looks better in the preview down the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter,everyone here is so helpful;its quite encouraging. Okay,I will add this info in my question now.

Comment: This is *probably* a better fit for somewhere like http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: First, you need to define "doesn't work". Do you get an error message from Matlab, or are you simply wondering why the output doesn't look any different? One problem I see is that you have fixed the length of the FFT to 64, which means that the difference between a vector of 100 and a vector of 8192 can't be seen.

Comment: @David No I don't get an error message but I don't get the desired output either. Let me attach an image of what I get if a take 8192 point FFT. My desired output should be a sinc with one sharp peak and very small sidelobes;but I can't get it.

Comment: It looks like the filter is working perfectly to me. Your input signal has a uniform PSD, and the filter is only passing the frequencies up to 0.6 F_nyquist. Why are you execting a sinc shape?

Comment: @David Ummm...because my teacher said so! Maybe I didn't get the question right then, I will ask him in person tomorrow. And thanks a lot for your help,such quick response is really motivating.

Comment: Just as a side note, the spectrum of a stream of random bits *is* a sinc function, but the bit rate needs to be significantly slower than the sample rate in order to see this in an FFT. In your case, the bit rate equals the sample rate, which is just white noise.

Comment: People answering Matlab questions at stackoverflow.com , too...